# How could work `\spanishdatedel` with datetime2 package

Tags: babel, spanish, datetime2

I'm asking if is possible to use `\spanishdatedel` commmand of [`babel-spanish`](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\spanishdatedel
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional}

\begin{document}
\today

\selectlanguage{english}

\today
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Desired output

> 16 de julio del 2020
>
> July 16, 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. datetime2 overrides the definition of `\today` from babel with its own definition so `\spanishdatedel` has no effect.

You can do this manually using the following:

```
\renewcommand*{\DTMspanishmonthyearsep}{%
 \space del\DTMtexorpdfstring{\protect~}{\space}}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you.